# Simple Proof in Pure Mathematics that has applicability

Tags: soft-question

I'm writing a report on the philosophy of pure mathematical knowledge, and how pure mathematics isn't what people commonly consider it, as non-applied. I want to see if anyone has an example of, or can make up a simple mathematical proof/theorem/example, in the realm of pure mathematics, that actually has an application, although one that cannot be seen a first sight.

I want this to be a brief thing that I can add in the report and explain,

I appreciate your help,

Comment: Such as number-theory and its applications in cryptogaphy?

Comment: You may want to check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem, particularly the "illustrations" part. I believe the Brouwer Fixed Point theorem also has applications in economics, but I don't know enough about that to really say.

Comment: [Cyclic redundancy checks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks) are a nice example of some concepts from abstract algebra with a surprising real world application - well let's treat the data bits as the coefficients of a polynomial ...

Comment: I recall an application of the Brouwer Fixed Point theorem in an explanation of a cause of heart fibrillation,There was a Scientific American article a very long time ago.I'm sorry I can't recall more

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Sure, it could be anything in pure mathematics. I simply want to demonstrate a small theorem or something that has applicability, to make a bigger point on the essay that I am doing. This shouldn't be something overly complicated, but significant. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Interesting comments, I appreciate all of your help. I really actually want to see something that is like for example, a small simple equation for finding all the even numbers up to any certain number, and then explain how this theorem (I want to show a small theorem) can be used in cryptography or to generate astronmical patters. (I know this is an absurd example, I couldnt think of anything else) All I want is a small mathematical theorem that can easily be made up. Thanks again.

Comment: If graph theory is enough pure for you, there are multiple theorems that are indirectly used in practice. For example in the USA the [National Resident Matching Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Resident_Matching_Program) uses matching theory results to assign medical school students to hospitals—although the current algorithm isn't pure anymore, it is still based on [stable matchings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) and related results.

Comment: Also, if I were to name _one_ concept that exemplifies how much pure math is useful (besides obvious things like numbers, etc.), it would be the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) (not cryptography, because its impact gets diluted between all the small results involved).

Comment: @dtldarek This is quite interesting. I guess I'm not rephrasing my question too well. I really want to add something like this (please note that this proof makes no sense whatsoever probably - but I'm just putting it down to make a point, not being a mathematician)  So, say x+y+z is a pure mathematical formula that allows us to estimate or find any even number. Now, I see a small proof, whatever that would be, and then I state how this can be used in information security. I don't necessarily want anything big. I just want to see a small formula with a proof and go from there.

Comment: @dtldarek Thanks for your kind and great help though!!!

Comment: If you are fixed on even/odd numbers: in many cities the houses/buildings are numbered with even numbers on one side of the street and odd on the other, in such case $2n$ and $2n+1$ are the formulas for these numbers.

Comment: @dtldarek  Can you firstly explain this a bit more? Additionally, does this constitute pure math? In my paper, I want to say: "Pure Mathematics once thought useless, indeed have a strong element of applicability, though it may not be realized initially. For example, cities the houses/buildings are numbered with even numbers on one side of the street and odd on the other. I want to explain what you suggested, but do you think this would fit my paper. Finally, can you explain this a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: @hariq Unfortunately, any example that I know of at the level of simplicity you require is trivial, and wouldn't be taken seriously. The even/odd numbers can be thought of as "pure math" in the context of group $\mathbb{Z}_2$, but this not even a tip of an iceberg. One of the reasons why people considered pure math useless, is that the useful bits are often a bit more complicated and we needed time to discover their applications.

Comment: On the other hand, there are a few places where you can see a glimpse of pure math, like the matching theory I mentioned, or [group testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_testing) which uses coding theory. If you are not familiar, the latter is, in my opinion, quite illuminating.